# How to implement pre-populated input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a pre-populated input field so that users can enter only necessary inputs. For example; input value should be *https://**[subdomain]**.xyz.com* but the user should enter only the **subdomain** value. Other parts of the URL will be fixed on the input field. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<span>https://<input placeholder="subdomain">.xyz.com</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this

```html
<span> 
  https://<input type="text" placeholder="enter domain name" /> 
  <select>
    <option vlaue="com">.com</option>
    <option vlaue="net">.net</option>
    <option vlaue="org">.org</option>
    <option vlaue="edu">.edu</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outerDiv{
  border:1px solid grey;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.innerTextBox{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: right;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">https://<input placeholder="subdomain" class="innerTextBox">.xyz.com</div>
```